# opposite of "atmospheric conditions"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am currently working on a paper that involves describing the conditions under which a rover sent to a celestial body (eg. the moon) operates. As a part of that, I want to say,

> The body of the rover was designed to shed the generated heat despite the [adj. no atmosphere] conditions.

The most natural solution for me is to use the word(?) *anatmospheric*, using *an*- to negate the adjective. But my word processor seems to believe that this is not a word, and some brief internet searches seem to indicate the same.

So my question:
Is "anatmospheric" a word? If so, would its meaning be most likely quite clear to someone with some loose familiarity with my subject matter? If not, what would be a better word or construction to communicate my meaning?

Comment: Why not just say "lack of atmosphere"?

Comment: I refer back later to "these conditions", so that would require changing a couple things a bit further down. "lack of atmosphere" does sound quite natural though.

Comment: What about "the **airless** conditions" (whatever the air may be on a given planet, even none)?

Comment: To my surprise, while "atmosphericless" has some use in scientific articles about celestial bodies, it doesn't appear in dictionaries either.

Comment: _Vacuum_. And you don't need to say "vacuum condition", either. If you're on a moon or an asteroid, you're in vacuum. (OK, except for Titan, but you're not talking about that)

Comment: You could just say *ambient*.

Comment: The most natural solution is to just say what it *does* do - it radiates excess heat.